# Implement swipe to go back in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swipe

Is there an easy solution to enable the function where the user swipes to get back? Couldn't find an easy solution that works for me.

Comment: Did you use navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, I already have a "back-Button"

Comment: So navigationController has a predefined swipe to back gesture. just swipe from the edge of the screen.

Comment: its not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIKit disables the default back gesture if you use any custom transitions. You can unset the navigationControllerDelegate to get back the back gesture. or implement your own back gesture through interactive transition.

Inside `viewDidLoad()` of the destination-ViewController following line does the trick:

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
```

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621847-interactivepopgesturerecognizer)

Comment: this is very wrong ! it have side effects on the navigation.